# Sci-fi book series with female protagonist named SPARTA

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a series of books that I read in the late 80s, early 90s about a girl that called herself SPARTA. In the 3rd book she went to Mars. In the last book she made herself into a fish so she could live underwater.

I think the lead male character was named Blake.

I remember that SPARTA was an acronym for a program she was involved with as a teen.

Comment: Venus Prime by Paul Preuss? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Prime

Comment: @Otis: you should post that as an answer. It's obviously correct.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Wasn't sure since I haven't read it and the Wikipedia entry didn't mention anything about turning into a fish. It looks like Richard already wrote it up, anyway.

Comment: @Otis - Sorry, chap. I didn't spot your comment before I posted.

Answer (score 7):

A quick google of the words "sparta", "blake" and "Mars" leads to the wikipedia page for [Venus Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Prime), a...

> "series of six science fiction novels written by Paul Preuss"...

...based on the short stories of Arthur C. Clarke.

> Volume 1 – Breaking Strain (based on the 1949 short story "Breaking
>   Strain") After her sudden escape from a mental institution, **an
>   amnesiac who calls herself Sparta seeks out the origins of her unusual
>   abilities. To this end, she adopts the identity of Ellen Troy and
>   becomes an inspector for the Space Guild.**
>
> On her first assignment as an Inspector, Sparta is sent to Port
>   Hesperus, the space station orbiting Venus, to investigate the
>   sabotage of the Space Queen, an old freighter. While there, she
>   encounters **Blake Redfield**, a young antique books expert who may hold
>   the key to her missing memories.

It's noted that her name is actually the acronym of the program that helped to genetically engineer her DNA

> Formerly enrolled in the mysterious SPARTA program under her birth
>   name, Linda Nagy... [etc]

---

*This answer has been confirmed by the querant in a since deleted comment:*

> *Thank you! This is it!*
>   *— user54473 Oct 18 '15 at 12:41*

Comment: @user54473 - Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the green tick on the left.

Comment: @SQB - Interesting. How did you know that there was a comment under this one?

Comment: _above_ your first comment, actually. Jenayah voiced that suspicion in chat, then a mod (Rand al'Thor) was able to confirm (but unfortunately unable to un-delete it). Lacking any other confirmation, I thought it best to edit it in to preserve the acceptance of your answer.

Comment: @SQB - Seems like very questionable judgement in flagging it.

Comment: I _think_ we had a drive-by "thank you" flagger a while ago.